# C#-Roslyn:Why the code conversion of the string to MethodDeclarationSyntax presents an exception

Tags: c#, roslyn

My code:

```cs
stringBuilder.AppendLine("}");
MethodDeclarationSyntax methodDeclaration = default;
var tmp = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(stringBuilder.ToString())
                          .GetRoot()
                          .DescendantNodes();


var list = tmp.OfType<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString());

    methodDeclaration = item as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

    if (methodDeclaration != null)
        break;
}
if (methodDeclaration is null)
    throw new Exception("No create Roslyn ...");
return methodDeclaration;
```

[image: Code]

string output there should be no problem:

```
public void T1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("666");
}
```

But cannot convert to MethodDeclarationSyntax,how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you expect what object the `list` variable is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid I may misunderstand what you are trying to achieve:
Reading your code I assume that you want to find the first [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods) declared in a given [SourceText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.text.sourcetext).

The *SourceText* you are providing does not contain a [MethodDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.methoddeclarationsyntax)!

The *CSharp* code

```cs
public void T1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("666");
}
```

is a [GlobalStatementSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.globalstatementsyntax), containing a [LocalFunctionStatementSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.localfunctionstatementsyntax).

In order for `T1` to become a *MethodDeclarationSyntax*, you want to put it into a **Type** such as a `class`, a `struct`, or an `interface`:

```cs
class C
{
    public void T1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("666");
    }
}
```

However, your program now prints both the entire Class and the contained Method to the console before it terminates the loop, because both [SyntaxNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxnode)s are of type [MemberDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.memberdeclarationsyntax):

- `void T1()` is of type *MethodDeclarationSyntax* that you expect
- `class C` is of type [ClassDeclarationSyntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.classdeclarationsyntax), which derives from *MemberDeclarationSyntax* because it could be nested in another class

I see that you are using *Visual Studio*. What helped me a lot while learning Roslyn and the **CSharpSyntaxTree** was (and still is) the [Syntax Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/syntax-visualizer).